# Combined Grappling Dummy and Bob punching bag for practice

Tags: training, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, equipment, grappling

I would like to practice at home both grappling and punching. For punching there is a boxing bag or Bob and for grappling there are grappling dummies such as bubba dummy and the like. I would like to know if there is a dummy that combines the two: punching bag with legs, hands and face such as Bob and grappling such as bubba dummy?

Comment: I know these exist - I'm interested in hearing from anyone who has had some experience with any of these and what the pros/cons are etc.

Comment: You could always go full throttle on a standing one and take it down to the ground to grapple.  I don't think that will keep good form though as much as a good anger management outlet...

Comment: In my experience EVERY grappling dummy doubles as a punching bag. Thick leather outer, dense inner padding. Do you have one that doesn't fit this criteria?

Comment: Thanks, @coinbird. I would like to use the dummy the same as Bob. It means that it will be able to stay on its own and have balance while boxing. In addition, I'll be able to use it for grappling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought someone might write in on here with an alternate, but apparently not.  So this is how you can make your own.

1. Get a very simple weighted standing bag like Bob, but you just need the bottom part so I recommend going cheaper.
2. Get a bubba dummy
3. Take off the top part of the weighted standing bag so you just have the bottom heavy part and the top part is missing.  You may need to literally just cut it off.
4. You then bind some industrial PVC into the base so that it's stationary.  Depending on what type of weight is utilized the binding substance may vary.
5. You carefully cut into the bubba dummy between the legs to ensure that the PVC can be inserted into it.  Please note that depending on the material it may be best to have the post with the weighted bottom a slightly smaller size PVC and put a slightly larger size PVC into the bubba dummy and then slide the PVC together.  Naturally this will add a hardness to the grappling part, even though the base of the bubba dummy will be there.  If it works well without the additional PVC and the hole in the bottom of bubba dummy then no worries.

Once you have this you can slide the bubba dummy on and off of the weighted punching stand.  This will allow you to punch and kick him and then pull him to the ground and grapple.

Note: Be sure to secure the plastic PVC to the weighted bottom and bubba dummy with a glue or substance that binds the PVC to they respective parts.  You don't want it slipping off.

Note2: The dummy will likely spin as hit when added to the weighted base.  You may want to add some pins to keep it from spinning, but then it might likely decrease your attack to grapple transitions as well.  The spinning might mimic actual human body reactions to hits which seems like the goal of this in the first place, if so no worries and enjoy.

Good luck

P.S. Not exactly what you describe, but this seems for both punch and grapple [punch and grapple](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FX6NDVO)